# Excel macro works for PC but not Mac

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, macos, activex

I have an Excel macro that connects to a SQL server database and displays data.  It works fine on a PC (Excel 2010 ver 14) but when I try it on a Mac (Excel 2011 14.1.4) it doesn't work.

It's saying it doesn't have the library for the ADODB that I'm using in the code.  I believe the library is ActiveX Data Objects 2.7.

How do I get around this?  Thank you very much!!

Comment: `ADODB` is a Windows database access technology based on ActiveX (which you mention in your question). You need to find the Mac alternative and use it instead in your OS X version. (You should specify which database engine you're using; I'm presuming it's SQL Server, but you should edit to add the proper tag. The proper database access technology can vary drastically based on the database you're trying to access.)

Comment: Thanks Ken, I figured that it wasn't supported so I've been searching all day for an alternative. Does anyone know a specific alternative I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `ActiveX Data Objects 2.7` on `Mac`. Read [this](http://asmiler.blogspot.in/2011/10/accessing-mssql-databases-from-excel.html).